# Finding subgroup of PSL(2,13) isomorphic to A4

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I need show PSL(2,13)=SL(2,13)/{id, -id} contains a subgroup isomorphic to A_4.
I wanted to work with the elements of order 3 in PSL(2,13) (since A_4 is generated by the 3-cycles), but I don't know how to explicitly relate the elements of order 3 in PSL(2,13) with the alternating group. 
Does anyone know a better way to approach this problem?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Since $A_4$ has a normal subgroup isomorphic with the Klein group, I think I would actually start there. Find two involutions $a$ and $b$ of $PSL(2,13)$ which commute, then find an element of order $3$ which maps $a$ to $b$ to $ab$.

Comment: If you know character theory then you can prove that $\text{PSL}(2,13)$ contains an $A_4$ without finding an explicit one. You just calculate the number of ways that the product of two elements of order $3$ has order $2$ - you'll find it is non-zero, As $\langle a, b | a^3 = b^3 =(ab)^2 = 1\rangle$ is a presentation of $A_4$ you are done. [An argument of G Higman.]

Comment: But since the field is of order $13$ we can in this case look at the Sylow-2-normalizer. It can't contain elements of order $7$ or $13$, as these would commute with an involution which can't be so. So the Sylow-2-normaliser has order 12. If it's not $A_4$ then too much centralises the element of order $3$.

Comment: @ancientmathematician How do you rule out the Sylow 2-normalizer having order $4$? (It's easy if you know Burnside's Transfer Theorem, but it's unclear what results we are allowed to use here.)

Comment: @ancientmathematician, I don't know character theory. In your second comment, should I try to show that a Sylow-2-normalizer is isomorphic to $A_4$ then?.

Comment: @DerekHolt. You are right, I assumed that it wasn't self-normalising, and can't see an easier argument than Burnside to eliminate that case. Otherwise I think the argument is staightforward if we calculate a few centralisers. But there must be a geometric argument "explaining" the existence of $A_4$, and I hope someone will give it.

Comment: @DerekHolt, I  don't know Burnside's Transfer Theorem. I know Sylow Theorems, Hall Theorems and I have basic knowledge in Group Theory (Isomorphism Theorems, Direct and Semidirect products). That's why I figured my only option was finding explicitly the two involutions and the 3-cycle as verret suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is useful to know that the order of an element in ${\rm SL}(2,q)$ is determined by its trace. We want to generate a subgroup of ${\rm SL}(2,q)$ of order $48$ isomorphic to ${\rm SL}(2,3)$; then its image in ${\rm PSL}(2,q)$ will be isomorphic to $A_4$.

To do that, it would be enough to find two elements $x,y$ of order $3$ (trace $-1$) in ${\rm SL}(2,q)$ with product of order $4$ (trace $0$), because then we would have $(xy)^2 = -I$, and the images of $x,y$ in ${\rm PSL}(2,q)$ would satisfy the relations of the presentation $\langle x,y \mid x^3=y^3=(xy)^2=1 \rangle$ of $A_4$ that was mentioned in the comment by ancientmathematician.

This is possible for all odd prime powers $q$, but in the case when $q \equiv 1 \bmod 4$, there is a solution
$$x = \left(\begin{array}{rr}-1&-1\\1&0\end{array}\right),\ \ 
y = \left(\begin{array}{rr}0&i\\i&-1\end{array}\right),\ \ 
xy = \left(\begin{array}{cc}-i&1-i\\0&i\end{array}\right),
$$
where $i^2=-1$. So, in the case $q=13$, we can take $i=5$.